# How to identify which class member is causing issue with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, com, xmlserializer

So I'm playing around with the `XmlSerializer`, and encountering a few challenges.
I have a third party XML file, so I'm constrained by an XML schema that I'm not a huge fan of.. and I want to try to essentially perform a proxy from this XML into VBA, so I need to go via COM.

I've managed to get a few classes working, essentially using XSD2 (CodeDom) to convert the XML Schema into a set of classes, and manipulate the C# classes to use `IList<>` implementing classes.  Which is where I believe the issue lies.  I have done this with several classes as a start, and it worked fine, I've since pushed this through CodeDom, and now have something in the realm of 335 classes/enumerations to deal with.

The exception that I'm getting is on the line

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(L5XSchema.RSLogix5000Content));
```

And the exception is: 
'CDF15337, DDB176069: Also fail in whidbey IEnumerable member with XmlAttributeAttribute'
(and the link to the only online reference for the Exception I can find https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializationWriterILGen.cs)

Does anyone know what the 'whidbey' reference is about?

Thankfully I believe I've identified the issue thanks to the IEnumerable XmlAttributeAttribute portion.
This is indeed the case.  And converting these back into Enum[] has allowed the `XmlSerializer` instance to be built. My XML schema for this section (one of the attributes) looks like this:

```xml
<xs:attribute name="CIPAxisExceptionAction" use="optional">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:list itemType="AxisExceptionActionEnum" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

Does anyone know of a way to utilise something like an `IList<>` for an XML Attribute value?

.NET Framework example issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ws5VMI
.NET Core example issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShO5UX

I'm currently still jumping through a few hoops to get the classes 'happy' with the `XmlSerializer` in accordance with the schema.  And also happy with COM.  That means no identifiable generic collections, so all my `List<>` members are needing to be wrapped in a `IList<>` implementing wrapper class to get pushed through the COM barrier.  Makes it very annoying when dealing with derived classes.

Does anyone know of a way to easily proxy generic collections in C# to COM?

Comment: Why are you manually creating classes. Why not use the xsd.exe utility to create the classes?  What I normally do to find the issue is to comment out sections of the classes until it works.  Then add back slowly the commented code.  If a property is missing in the c# code, xml still deserialize and just ignore the xml tag.  I also sometimes fill the classes with sample data and then serialize.  Then compare the serialize xml against the input xml file.  Remember c# serialization will not work if the root xml is an array.  Root tag must be a singleton.

Comment: I can't reproduce your exception on .Net Core.  If I mark an array of enums with `[XmlAttribute]` like so: `[XmlAttribute] public AxisExceptionActionEnum [] CIPAxisExceptionAction { get; set; }` it actually serializes successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/BNSEaL.  It also works with other collection types, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5CmbIv.   Can you share a [mcve]?  Possibly you've done something unexpected that has uncovered an `XmlSerializer` bug.  No exception on .Net Framework either. see https://dotnetfiddle.net/JrhEM9.

Comment: @jdweng I think you missed the part where I mentioned CodeDom (xsd2).  Xsd by itself has too many limitations for this situation. It doesn't create lists as List<> members, but only as [] members, which makes add/remove operations too difficult for clients of my library.  It also doesn't tag things as ComVisible() as I need, or add ClassInterface attributes.  Xsd internally uses CodeDom, but in a fixed way (which doesn't work for me here).

Comment: @dbc Thank you so much for the involved testing.
Here's a minimal reproducible based on your framework for:
.NET Core https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShO5UX
.NET Framework https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ws5VMI

As I mentioned, I need to support COM, so can't have List<> generics exposed directly.  They have to be through an IList<> implementing class (to get the IEnumerable and ICollection interfaces which is what VBA appears to handle ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found what appears to be a bug in the code-generation algorithm of `XmlSerializer`, specifically for *custom collections of enums marked with `[XmlAttribute]` that do not implement the non-generic interface [`System.Collections.ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection)*.  The workaround seems to be to explicitly implement this interface on the custom collection.

Details are as follows.  Say we have a type like the following:

```
public class RSLogix5000Content
{
    [XmlAttribute] public List<AxisExceptionActionEnum>  CIPAxisExceptionAction { get; set; }
}

public enum AxisExceptionActionEnum
{
    Default = 0,
    Value1 = (1<<0),
    Value2 = (1<<1)
}
```

When serialized to XML, the attribute is successfully serialized as a string containing a sequence of space-separated values as follows (demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/meWCgU)):

```
<RSLogix5000Content CIPAxisExceptionAction="Value1 Value2 Value1" />
```

However, if the `List<AxisExceptionActionEnum>` is replaced by a custom collection implementing `IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>` like so (demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ShO5UX)):

```
public class RSLogix5000Content
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public AxisExceptionActionEnumCollection CIPAxisExceptionAction { get; set; }
}

public enum AxisExceptionActionEnum
{
    Default = 0,
    Value1 = (1<<0),
    Value2 = (1<<1)
}

public class AxisExceptionActionEnumCollection : IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>
{
    private System.Collections.Generic.List<AxisExceptionActionEnum> axisExceptionActionEnumField = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AxisExceptionActionEnum>();

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public AxisExceptionActionEnum this[int index] {
        get {
            return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField))[index];
        }
        set {
            ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField))[index] = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public int Count {
        get {
            return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Count;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool IsReadOnly {
        get {
            return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public void Add(AxisExceptionActionEnum item) {
        ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(AxisExceptionActionEnum item) {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(AxisExceptionActionEnum[] array, int arrayIndex) {
        ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int IndexOf(AxisExceptionActionEnum item) {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, AxisExceptionActionEnum item) {
        ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(AxisExceptionActionEnum item) {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<AxisExceptionActionEnum> GetEnumerator() {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then an inscrutable exception is thrown:

> ```
> System.NotSupportedException: Also fail in IEnumerable member with XmlAttributeAttribute
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.WriteMember(SourceInfo source, AttributeAccessor attribute, TypeDesc memberTypeDesc, String parent)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.WriteStructMethod(StructMapping mapping)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.GenerateMethod(TypeMapping mapping)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationILGen.GenerateReferencedMethods()
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.GenerateEnd()
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateRefEmitAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace, String location)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
>    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
> ```

Why might this happen?  Well, one difference between `List<AxisExceptionActionEnum>` and `AxisExceptionActionEnumCollection` is that the former implements the old non-generic interfaces [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) and `ICollection`, maybe the lack of non-generic access to the collection is causing problems for the serializer?  To test this I implemented `ICollection` for your collection:

```
public class AxisExceptionActionEnumCollection : IList<AxisExceptionActionEnum>, ICollection
{
    // Remainder unchanged

    #region ICollection Members

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((System.Collections.IList)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    int ICollection.Count { get { return Count; } }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized { get { return ((System.Collections.IList)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).IsSynchronized; } }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot { get { return ((System.Collections.IList)(this.axisExceptionActionEnumField)).SyncRoot; } }

    #endregion
}
```

And the problem resolved itself!  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NbjSD5).

Notes:

- It was only necessary to implement the non-generic `ICollection` interface -- not the non-generic `IList`.
- `XmlSerializer` is perfectly happy to serialize your generic-only collection *as long as it is marked with `[XmlElement]` instead of `[XmlAttribute]`*:

  ```
  public class RSLogix5000Content
  {
      [XmlElement]
      public AxisExceptionActionEnumCollection CIPAxisExceptionAction { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1BYsyN).
- Since `ICollection` doesn't even have an `Add(object value)` method, this definitely feels like an `XmlSerializer` bug.  You might want to report an issue to Microsoft, e.g. [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues).
- I was a bit surprised that serializing a collection of enums as an attribute resulted in a space-separated sequence of enum values; nothing in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) suggests this should work.

  But since a `[Flags]` enum is also serialized as a space-separated sequence of enum values, it seems that trying to serialize a list of flag enums as an XML attribute also fails with an inscrutable exception:

  ```
  public class RSLogix5000Content
  {
      [XmlAttribute] public List<AxisExceptionActionEnum>  CIPAxisExceptionAction { get; set; }
  }

  [Flags]
  public enum AxisExceptionActionEnum
  {
      Default = 0,
      Value1 = (1<<0),
      Value2 = (1<<1)
  }
  ```

  > ```
  > Failed with unhandled exception: 
  > System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'RSLogix5000Content'.
  > ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'CIPAxisExceptionAction'.
  > ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'AxisExceptionActionEnum'.
  > ---> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
  > at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
  > at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
  > at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0)
  > at System.SR.Format(String resourceFormat, Object p1)
  > at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportEnumMapping(EnumModel model, String ns, Boolean repeats)
  > ```

  Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jMIBBL).